# possible give two datasource to one repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

This is my repeater control with data coming from `[Patient_Master]` table. But `Visit_Date` is coming from `[Patient_Visit]` table. How can I show `Visit_Date` to the same repeater? Is it possible to give two datasources to one repeater? `[Patient_Master]` and `[Patient_Visit]` have a relation:

```asp
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterPatientList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeaterPatientList_ItemDataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr onclick="selectRow(this);">
            <td class="csstablelisttd" style="display:none" >
                <asp:Label ID="lblPID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PID")%>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd" >
                <a href="#" onclick="return showPatient('<%#Eval("PID") %>')"><%#Eval("Patient_Name")%></a>                             
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">         
                <asp:Label ID="lblPatientName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Patient_ID")%>'></asp:Label>
            </td>   
            <td class="csstablelisttd" >
                <asp:Label ID="lblSex" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Sex")%>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                <asp:Label ID="lblPatientsBirthDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Patients_Birth_Date")%>'></asp:Label>
            </td>                           
            <td class="csstablelisttd">         
                <asp:Label ID="lblLastVisitDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Visit_Date")%>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">                           
                <a href="#" onclick="return showSchedulePatient('<%#Eval("PID") %>')">New</a>
            </td>   
            <td id="tdTodaysVisit" bgcolor="#00cc66" runat="server">                           
                <a href="#" onclick="return showSchedulePatient('<%#Eval("PID") %>')"><span class="cssgreen">Today's Visit</span></a>
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                <%--<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkSchedule" CssClass="csshyperlinkSchedulePatient" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("PID", "~/Create_Order.aspx?ID={0}") %>'>Schedule</asp:HyperLink>--%>
                <a href="#" onclick="return showSchedulePatient('<%#Eval("PID") %>')">Schedule</a>
            </td>                           
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use an outer join between patient_master and patient_visit.